# Keyboard shortcuts for the Google Apps Script code editor menu - how to use with / reconfigure for different keyboard layouts

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, google-apps-script-editor

I am learning Google Apps Scripts, using the code editor as instructed in the Codelabs tutorials. I am using a Norwegian keyboard (Lenovo Thinkpad), so some keyboard shortcuts don't work for me (eg Word completion and Toggle comment, as shown in pic 1). My "/" sits on the number 7 key and requires Shift to reach it (pic 2). Prefixing these shortcuts with Shift doesn't work.

Any suggestions how I can either:

a) make these shortcuts work?
or
b) assign new key combinations for them?

I don't want to alter keyboard layout. It has to remain as Norwegian.

Thanks.

[image: Keyboard shortcuts for the Google Apps Script Programming Environment]
[image: 7 key]

Comment: This must be the most unsuccessful question ever! 8 views in 7 days. Anyone got any advice on how to find a solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided just to bite the bullet and try various combinations. The one that worked is Ctrl+', using the *' key to the left of the Return key. Not sure why, but I'm happy with that.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot - very useful! For german keyboards this works too, but the symbol at the same keyboard position is a "#" in this case.

Comment: This works for me too! I was going crazy!! Thank you so much! In my case, for a Spanish keyboard, that key corresponds to "Ç" and "}"